# Update from multiple rows by concatenating strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to update a row from multiple rows?

I'm trying to update my column by concatenating the string found but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to concatenate all the `sord.type` in the column `sor.type` where `sord.orderid = sor.orderid`

The query:

```
update sor
set sor.type = sor.type + " " + (select sord.type
                                 from sales.OrderDetails sord
                                 where sord.orderid = sor.orderid)
from sales.Orders sor
```

I want to get the sum

Error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: join that table instead of making a sub select

Comment: The error says a subquery returned more than one value. Did you happen to run your subquery by itself and confirm the output?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.  Clearly there are multiple records, but are there multiple sord.type's ?

Comment: @dfundako yes it returns more than 1 value thats why im trying to concatenating

Comment: @John Cappelletti yes multiple sord.type. I need to get all the sord.type for the same Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data, I'm not sure if `sor.type + ' ' +` is necessary

Try the following without the update.  If you are satisfied witht the results, remove the top select and un-comment the update

```
Select 
--update sor set sor.type =
  sor.type + ' ' + (Select Stuff((Select Distinct ' ' +sord.type 
                                                From  sales.OrderDetails sord 
                                                Where sord.orderid = sor.orderid 
                                                For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
from sales.Orders sor
```

Again, without seeing sample data, there could be a more performant approach i.e. distinct and join

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: @sari Happy to help  :)